# External Monitor keeps blacking and come back randomly

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

Since Ubuntu 18.04 I can't get any external screen to work properly with my laptop (Asus ROG G552VW - Nvidia GTX 960m). It worked well on 17.04.
Also everything works well if I boot on my Windows partition.

When I plug an external monitor with HDMI, the monitor keeps blacking out and coming back completely randomly. Sometimes it blacks out 1 second, sometimes 50.

The external monitor stays black if I use it as Single Display.
Tried this on several monitors and it's always the same result.
Same result whether prime-select is on nvidia or intel.

I think I started from 16.04 and always did the updates until 19.04 using the Software Updates of Ubuntu. Kept getting more and more bugs so I repaired 19.04 using a USB stick not too long ago, hoping that it would also fix the monitor problems. Bugs disappeared, but monitor is still bugging the same way.

The current external Monitor I can test with is :

Acer VG270

- Size: 27"
- Maximum Resolution: (Full HD)1920 x 1080 @ 75 Hz

My GRUB config:

```
$ cat /etc/default/grub | grep GRUB_CMD
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

I've been looking around internet but can't find the same problem or can't apply the solutions to mine. tried a bunch of things using `xrandr` but to no avail.

Happy to provide more conf/details if needed.

Comment: Try refresh rate of 60 HZ to see if that is more stable.

Comment: I did change the refresh to 60Hz and it seemed to take longer to come to a black screen the first time. But then it blacks again randomly.

Comment: If the change had some positive benefit it might help to cold boot both the monitor and computer. Sometimes warm reboots are different that power off/on switch.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I tried but it didn't work. I tried to plugged in the screen today after months of not using it (thinking updates might have fixed the problem), and it kind of worked flawlessly 1hour, and started to do again the black/work/black/work totally randomly again.